# APPSACAN: Authentication.Credentials.Unprotected

Tags: c#, web-services, code-security, bluemix-app-scan

I did a scan with the APPSCAN to an application, and the report says there's a vulnerability called:"Authentication. Credentials. Unprotected" and it's in that method:

```
public string CrearSeguimientoCertificador(string UsuarioServicio, string ContrasenaServicio, long Idproceso, string IdCertificador, string Observaciones, int ResultadoExamen, string CategoriaFinal)
{
    string resultado = null;
    ServicioTransaccionalClient svc = new ServicioTransaccionalClient();

    try
    {
        svc.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = UsuarioServicio;
        svc.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = ContrasenaServicio;

        resultado = svc.CrearSeguimientoCertificador(Idproceso, IdCertificador, Observaciones, ResultadoExamen, CategoriaFinal, "");
        svc.Close();

        return resultado;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (svc != null)
            svc.Abort();
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

This is because I'm sending web service credentials without protection or encryption, but I don't know how to fix this. Could somebody point me out in which direction to go in order to solve this problem?